# upload image to wordpress media library failed for custom post type

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, media, media-library

image upload failed. I tried to upload gym logo as thumbnail image for gym post type. All the form elements are working. But image upload is not working. images are not appearing in WordPress media library. Help Me to find error in my code.

'''

```
 add_shortcode( 'gym_submission_form',  'gym_submission_form_shortcode' );

 ob_start();
  
    function gym_submission_form_shortcode() {
  
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit_gym'] ) ) {
   
  // Sanitize and validate form data
    
   $gym_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gym_name'] );
    
   $gym_address = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gym_address'] );
      
    $gym_phone = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gym_phone'] );
        
    $gym_district = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gym_district'] );
    


      $gym_thana = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gym_thana'] );
    

       $gym_slogan= sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gym_slogan'] );
    
     // 2 variable for checkbox group saving
    // Get the selected payment methods as an array . if payment method selected take array if not ampty
 $payment_methods = isset( $_POST['gym_payment'] ) ? $_POST['gym_payment'] : array();
  // Convert the array to a string separated by a delimiter
 $payment_methods_string = implode( '|', $payment_methods );
  //  sanitize and validate the file input before processing it:        
  if ( isset( $_FILES['gym_logo'] ) && ! empty( $_FILES['gym_logo']['name'] ) ) {
$allowed_types = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' );
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['gym_logo'];

// Sanitize the file name
$sanitized_file_name = sanitize_file_name( $uploaded_file['name'] );

// Validate the file type
$uploaded_file_type = wp_check_filetype( $sanitized_file_name, $allowed_types );
if ( ! $uploaded_file_type['ext'] || ! $uploaded_file_type['type'] ) {
    // Invalid file type
    wp_die( 'Invalid file type.' );
}

// Validate the file size
$max_file_size = wp_max_upload_size();
if ( $uploaded_file['size'] > $max_file_size ) {
    // File size too large
    wp_die( 'File size too large.' );
}

// Move the file to the uploads directory
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
 $file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $sanitized_file_name );
$file_path = $upload_dir['path'] .'/'. $file_name;
move_uploaded_file( $uploaded_file['tmp_name'], $file_path );
}
    // Create the new gym post
    $new_gym = array(
        'post_title' => $gym_name,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_type' => 'gym',
    );
    $new_gym_id = wp_insert_post( $new_gym );
    
    // Save meta data
    if ( $new_gym_id ) {
         

        update_post_meta( $new_gym_id, 'gym_address', $gym_address );
        update_post_meta( $new_gym_id, 'gym_phone', $gym_phone );
        update_post_meta( $new_gym_id, 'gym_district', $gym_district );
        update_post_meta( $new_gym_id, 'gym_thana', $gym_thana );
        update_post_meta( $new_gym_id, 'gym_slogan', $gym_slogan );
        update_post_meta( $new_gym_id,'gym_payment', $payment_methods_string);
        update_post_meta( $new_gym_id, '_thumbnail_id',   $file_path );
        

    }  
    // Redirect the user to the thank you page
    wp_redirect( '/thank-you/' );
    exit;
}

// Display the gym submission form
?>
<form method="post">
  <label for="gym_logo">Gym Logo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="gym_logo" id="gym_logo" accept="image/*" required>

    <label for="gym_name">Gym Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="gym_name" required>
    
    <label for="gym_address">Gym Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="gym_address" required>
    
    <label for="gym_phone">Gym Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="gym_phone" required>
    
    <label for="gym_district">Select a district:</label>
    <select id="district" name="gym_district" onchange="populateThana()" required>
    <option value="">Choose a district</option>
<option value="Dhaka">Dhaka</option>
<option value="Chittagong">Chittagong</option>
   </select>
<label for="gym_thana">Select a thana:</label>
 <select id="thana" name="gym_thana" required>
  <option value="">Choose a thana</option>
 </select>
 <label for="gym_slogan">Slogan:</label>
<input type="text" name="gym_slogan" id="gym_slogan" required>
 <label for="gym_payment">Payment Method:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mobile_payment" name="gym_payment[]" value="Mobile Payment"> Mobile Payments<br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="cash" name="gym_payment[]" value="Cash">cash<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="credit_cards" name="gym_payment[]" value="Credit Cards"> credit cards
<input type="submit" name="submit_gym" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php

return ob_get_clean();}
```